# Why is Rails not capturing one of my submitted form parametesr in my controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, submit, form-parameter

I'm using Rails 4.2.3 with MySql 5.5.37.  I recently change the name and type of my column and now when I submit my Rails form that form field, "selection_id," is not getting captured.  Below is my Rails form ...

```
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :day %><br>
        <%= f.hidden_field :day, :validate => true %>
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :selection_id %><br>
        <div class="styled-select"><%= collection_select(:user_selection, :selection_id, @selections, :id, :description, {:prompt => true}) %></div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :total %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :total, :size => 4, :validate => true %>
      </div>
```

And here is the HTML that gets output to the browser ...

```
    <div class="field">
       <label for="user_selection_day">Day</label><br>
       <input validate="true" type="hidden" value="02/07/2016" name="user_selection[day]" id="user_selection_day" />
       <div id="datepicker"></div>
     </div>
     <div class="field">
       <div class="field_with_errors"><label for="user_selection_selection_id">selection</label></div><br>
       <div class="styled-select"><div class="field_with_errors"><select name="user_selection[selection_id]" id="user_selection_selection_id"><option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="3">option 1</option>
    <option value="4">option 2</option></select></div></div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label for="user_selection_total">Total</label><br>
        <input size="4" validate="true" type="text" value="1" name="user_selection[total]" id="user_selection_total" />
      </div>
```

I can see this data getting submitted in Chrome ...

```
    user_selection[day]:02/19/2016
    user_selection[selection_id]:3
    user_selection[total]:9
```

but on my controller side, when I try and output the params, only two of the three are printing out.  This "puts"

```
      def create
        @current_user = User.find(session["user_id"])
        ...
        puts user_selection_params
```

prints

```
    {"day"=>"02/19/2016", "total"=>"9"}
```

Why is this other field getting lost and how can I fix it?

Comment: And your `user_object_params` is defined as...? You are probably missing `:object_id` from permitted list of attributes. You should have: `params.require(:user_object).permit(:day, :total, :user_id)`

Comment: Oh right, taht's where I missed it.  Forgot to define it in there.  Thanks ,-

Answer (score 1):

You are having this problem because `#object_id` is a method defined on Object, the class that all Ruby objects extend.   In other words, it's reserved by Ruby itself and can't be used when naming database fields / model attributes.   You're going to have to rename that column/association to something else.

As a side note, it's not idiomatic Ruby to include the word "Object" in your class name.  Arguably the class should just be named `User`, instead of `UserObject`.

Reference: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id

Answer (score 1):

Please don't use **object_id** in your model.

There should be no **column named** object_id in the **database**.

**object_id** is a **default methods** that all (except BasicObject in Ruby 1.9) objects have ...

(see [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Object.html#M001004)).

Comment: I didn't actually use "object_id", taht was just obfuscated code for the purpose of the question.  Anyway, the comment to my question answered it.